# Unable to switch to iframe in Selenium chromedriver when iframe is directly under body tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

driver.switchTo().frame(iframe) works fine for iframes which are not directly under body tag.

Ex: `<body><div><iframe></iframe></div></body>`

iframe in w3schools is not directly under body tag.
https://www.w3schools.com/

[image: iframe in w3schools.com]

Selenium webdriver fails to switch to iframes directly under body tag.

Ex: `<body><iframe></iframe></body>`

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-payments-demo

[image: stripe demo site]

Selenium Jar used: selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef)
```

Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Please note there is no error thrown. The driver is still in default frame even after `driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);`.

Same issue is over here :
https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/zyg6CvRteQ8

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: How did you confirm that the driver's scope is in the parent frame?

Comment: I confirmed by finding the same iframe again in document, which I should not have If  driver had switched to iframe.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I believe my code is fine since the code is working for iframes which are not directly under body tag.